# Html 5 canvas trouble

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to practice with HTML5 canvas drawing so I came up with this. I should result in a yellow star that is *overlapped* by a green silhouette of a bust (the head and shoulders of a person).

However if the drawStar() line is un-commented, the green silhouette is not drawn. Is this Working code is not as important as an explanation of what is happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/xiondark2008/LYfHJ/2/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    h6{
        -webkit-margin-before: .5em;
        -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    }
    label{
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="19" height="19" 
        style="border:1px solid d3d3d3;">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
function drawProfile(ctx,x,y,width,height) {
    this.flp = false;
    this.x = function(r){ return Math.floor(width*(this.flp?1-r:r)); }
    this.y = function(r){ return Math.floor(height*r); }

    ctx.save();

    ctx.translate( x, y );
    ctx.fillStyle="#40FF00";

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( this.x(0), this.y(1) );
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(
        this.x(0),      this.y(125/190),
        this.x(70/190), this.y(170/190),
        this.x(75/190), this.y(120/190)
    );
    ctx.lineTo( this.x(95/190), this.y(130/190) );
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(
        this.x(40/190), this.y(130/190),
        this.x(30/190), this.y(0), 
        this.x(95/190), this.y(0)
    );

    this.flp = true;

    ctx.bezierCurveTo(
        this.x(30/190), this.y(0),
        this.x(40/190), this.y(130/190), 
        this.x(95/190), this.y(130/190)
    );
    ctx.lineTo( this.x(75/190), this.y(120/190) );
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(
        this.x(70/190), this.y(170/190),
        this.x(0), this.y(125/190),
        this.x(0), this.y(1)
    );
    ctx.fill();

    this.flp = false;

    ctx.restore();
}

function drawStar(ctx,x,y,height) {

    var pnts = 5,
        rad = height/(1-Math.cos(0.8*Math.PI));

    this.x = function(p,dst){
        return dst * Math.sin( (p/pnts)*2*Math.PI );
    }
    this.y = function(p,dst){
        return dst * Math.cos( (p/pnts)*2*Math.PI ) * -1;
    }
    this.movePct = function(a,b,pct){
        var f = (function(x){
                var m = (b.y-a.y)/(b.x-a.x);
                return m*x+(a.y-(a.x*m));
            }).bind(),
            r = b.x - a.x,
            point = {};

        point.x = a.x+(r*pct);
        point.y = f(point.x);

        return point;
    }
    this.transPoints = function(s,p,e,pct){
        var sp = this.movePct(s,p,pct),
            ep = this.movePct(e,p,pct);

        return [sp,ep];
    }

    ctx.save();

    ctx.translate( x+rad, y+rad );
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffff00";

    ctx.beginPath();

    for(var i=0;i<pnts;i++){
        var dst = rad/2,
            s = { x: this.x( i+0.5, dst ),
                  y: this.y( i+0.5, dst ) },
            p = { x: this.x( i+1, rad ),
                  y: this.y( i+1, rad ) },
            e = { x: this.x( i+1.5, dst ),
                  y: this.y( i+1.5, dst ) },
            t = this.transPoints(s,p,e,.75);

        if(i==0){ ctx.moveTo( s.x, s.y ); }

        ctx.lineTo(t[0].x, t[0].y);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(p.x, p.y, t[1].x, t[1].y);
        ctx.lineTo(e.x, e.y);
    }
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.restore();

}

function draw(c) {

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    this.x = function(r){ return c.width*r; }
    this.y = function(r){ return c.height*r; }

    ctx.shadowBlur=this.y(1/19);
    ctx.shadowColor="black";

    //drawStar( ctx, this.x(-3/19), this.y(-1/19), this.y(20/19) );
    drawProfile( ctx, this.x(6/19), this.y(1/19), this.x(18/19), this.y(18/19) );


    if(0){
        ctx.clearRect( this.x(1), this.y(0), this.x(1), this.y(1) );
        ctx.clearRect( this.x(0), this.y(1), this.x(1), this.y(1) );
    }

}

draw( document.getElementById("myCanvas") );
```

Comment: You script looks overly complicated compared to what it does, and it is confusing to reference this in a function that doesn't seem, at the first look, to be called as an object method. You should first re-think your architecture and you'll probably find problems a lot easier. There is nothing worse than useless complexity.

Comment: I'm with @Virus721 on this one.  Your code looks really complicated.

Comment: Try [link] http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp[/link] if you are a fresher [/link] and this [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Canvas_tutorial [/link] for all with complete defination

Comment: Yeah, I guess I did get carried away a bit on with this. I the advise of @Virus721 and re-wrote the code and now it works fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `this` in your functions. In the context here, `this` is bound to `window` (there are lots of resources out there about how to use `this`, and you're doing it incorrectly).

In each function that you use `this`, is is bound to the same thing (`window`) so they over-write each other's variables. (This is because of the way you're using the functions. If you `new`ed them it would be a different story).

So

1. your `draw()` method sets `this.x`, which is actually `window.x`,
2. then passes it to `drawStar()` as an argument
3. the `drawStar()` function method changes the value of `this.x` (which is `window.x`) and returns back to `draw()`
4. then `draw()` calls `drawProfile()` with `this.x` (which is `window.x`), except this time its value is a function rather than the float value you wanted it to be.
5. drawProfile expected the argument to be a float, but now it's a function

(for `x` read `x` and `y`)

You can do this all with closures and variables. Remove the `this`es and your program will work. Probably.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fell victim to over complicated code as a result of many "small" changes.

Comment: It happens to everyone. If you can't tell what's wrong by looking at it, a good start is often to re-structure it until you can.

Answer (score 0):

Joe is right. You are overwriting the this.x and this.y functions. I don't know why you are doing this. I made a workaround by resetting the this.x and this.y functions to their old value at the end of the functions drawProfile and drawStar:

```
function drawProfile(ctx,x,y,width,height) {
    var oldX = this.x, //storing the old values for this.x ...
        oldY = this.y; // ... and this.y
    this.flp = false;
    this.x = function(r){ return Math.floor(width*(this.flp?1-r:r)); }
    this.y = function(r){ return Math.floor(height*r); }

    ctx.save();

    ctx.translate( x, y );
    ctx.fillStyle="#40FF00";

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( this.x(0), this.y(1) );
    ctx.bezierCurveTo( this.x(0), this.y(125/190),
                       this.x(70/190), this.y(170/190),
                       this.x(75/190), this.y(120/190)
                      );
    ctx.lineTo( this.x(95/190), this.y(130/190) );
    ctx.bezierCurveTo( this.x(40/190), this.y(130/190),
                       this.x(30/190), this.y(0), 
                       this.x(95/190), this.y(0)
                      );

    this.flp = true;

    ctx.bezierCurveTo( this.x(30/190), this.y(0),
                       this.x(40/190), this.y(130/190), 
                       this.x(95/190), this.y(130/190)
                      );
    ctx.lineTo( this.x(75/190), this.y(120/190) );
    ctx.bezierCurveTo( this.x(70/190), this.y(170/190),
                       this.x(0), this.y(125/190),
                       this.x(0), this.y(1)
                      );
    ctx.fill();

    this.flp = false;

    ctx.restore();

    this.x = oldX; //Restoring old values
    this.y = oldY;
}

function drawStar(ctx,x,y,height)
{
    var pnts = 5,
        rad = height/(1-Math.cos(0.8*Math.PI)),
        oldX = this.x, //storing the old values for this.x ...
        oldY = this.y; // ... and this.y

    this.x = function(p,dst){
        return dst * Math.sin( (p/pnts)*2*Math.PI );
    }
    this.y = function(p,dst){
        return dst * Math.cos( (p/pnts)*2*Math.PI ) * -1;
    }
    this.movePct = function(a,b,pct){
        var f = (function(x){
            var m = (b.y-a.y)/(b.x-a.x);
            return m*x+(a.y-(a.x*m));
        }).bind(),
            r = b.x - a.x,
            point = {};

        point.x = a.x+(r*pct);
        point.y = f(point.x);

        return point;
    }
    this.transPoints = function(s,p,e,pct){
        var sp = this.movePct(s,p,pct),
            ep = this.movePct(e,p,pct);

        return [sp,ep];
    }

    ctx.save();

    ctx.translate( x+rad, y+rad );
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffff00";

    ctx.beginPath();

    for(var i=0;i<pnts;i++){
        var dst = rad/2,
            s = { x: this.x( i+0.5, dst ),
                 y: this.y( i+0.5, dst ) },
            p = { x: this.x( i+1, rad ),
                 y: this.y( i+1, rad ) },
            e = { x: this.x( i+1.5, dst ),
                 y: this.y( i+1.5, dst ) },
            t = this.transPoints(s,p,e,.75);

        if(i==0){ ctx.moveTo( s.x, s.y ); }

        ctx.lineTo(t[0].x, t[0].y);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(p.x, p.y, t[1].x, t[1].y);
        ctx.lineTo(e.x, e.y);
    }
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.restore();

    this.x = oldX; //Resetting the old values
    this.y = oldY;
}

function draw(c)
{

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    this.x = function(r){ return c.width*r; }
    this.y = function(r){ return c.height*r; }

    ctx.shadowBlur=this.y(1/19);
    ctx.shadowColor="black";

    drawStar( ctx, this.x(-3/19), this.y(-1/19), this.y(20/19) );
    drawProfile( ctx, this.x(6/19), this.y(1/19), this.x(18/19), this.y(18/19) );



    if(0){
        ctx.clearRect( this.x(1), this.y(0), this.x(1), this.y(1) );
        ctx.clearRect( this.x(0), this.y(1), this.x(1), this.y(1) );
    }

}

draw( document.getElementById("myCanvas") );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhaXM/